# Encoding primes via ranks of sign matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

<sub>[Crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/443265) at MathOverflow</sub>

---

Recently I came across a very simply defined family of matrices: for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, set $A_n := (a_{ij})_{1 \le i, j \le n}$, where

$$\displaystyle a_{ij} := (-1)^{\big\lfloor \dfrac{2(i-1)(j-1)}{n} \big\rfloor}$$

These are [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem#Equivalence_and_normalization_of_%7B1,_%E2%88%921%7D_matrices) $\pm 1$ symmetric $n \times n$ matrices. The first few are:

$$
A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
     1&1\\
     1&-1
     \end{bmatrix},
A_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
     1&1&1\\
     1&1&-1\\
     1&-1&1
     \end{bmatrix},
A_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
     1&1&1&1\\
     1&1&-1&-1\\
     1&-1&1&-1\\
     1&-1&-1&1
     \end{bmatrix}, \ldots
$$

Computing $\operatorname{rank}(A_n)$ for small $n$ quickly suggests a pattern:

$$\operatorname{rank}(A_n) = \sigma_0(n) + \Big\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \Big\rfloor$$

where $\sigma_0(n)$ is the number (= sum of $0^\text{th}$ powers) of divisors of $n$. My question is:

> Is this formula for $\operatorname{rank}(A_n)$ true for all $n$?

If so, then since the minimal value of $\sigma_0$ is $2$, which occurs exactly for prime $n$, one would have $\operatorname{rank}(A_n) = \big\lfloor \frac{n+3}{2} \big\rfloor$ is minimal $\iff n$ is prime. (This would, in my opinion, be an interesting encoding of the primes in a purely linear-algebraic fashion.)

I have tested this up to $n = 30$. To save some trouble, this is [A361003](https://oeis.org/A361003) in OEIS (coincidentally just added last week!). A combinatorial proof e.g. via [A361001](https://oeis.org/A361001) would be fine. If anyone knows more about this family of matrices I would be happy to read more.

Comment: My computer has checked that it's true up to $n=1024$.  (And even so I don't exactly believe it :) .)

Comment: @JBL Your standards for numerical evidence are perhaps higher than mine :)